# what does advertising topics mean?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i just do command rosbag play -d 4

then commend window print this : Waiting 4 seconds after advertising topics..

i dont get what does 'advertising topic' mean.

plz somebody let me know clearly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200594/what-does-advertising-topics-mean?/) by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbag is telling you that in 4 seconds after all the publishers are created, it will start to publish the data. This delay will allow all the XMLRPC handshake to be done by the subscribers.
In pseudo code that look like this :

```
Nodehandle n
pub = n.advertise("topic")
sleep(4)
while(data to publish in bag file) {
 pub.publish(data);
 sleep(nextDataDate-now);
}
```

In the Talker / Listener sample [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) the takler "advertise" roscore that a topic exists...

When  Node Talker Advertise that a topic exists, it is equivalent to say : "Hi roscore, I am Node "Talker", and I publish a data called "chatter", if some one is interested (subscribing) for this data, I am reachable on this URI "...

---

Originally posted by [abarral](https://answers.ros.org/users/1825/abarral/) with karma: 138 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2